# Как сделать так, чтобы введённые в выведенные данные сохранялись при перезапуске приложения?

Tags: java, javafx, исключения, gui, сериализация

Пишу программу на java с использованием javafx, хочу сделать так, чтобы данные, которые я ввожу и получаю после работы программы, сохранялись и выводились на экран при перезапуске программы, пытался сделать это при помощи сериализации, но, по какой-то причине, программа начала выдавать ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы она работала как надо

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Трудочасы 3.0");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}





 package sample;
    import java.io.*;

    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;

    import javax.script.ScriptException;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;

    public class Controller {

        @FXML
        private TextField dni;

        @FXML
        private TextField num;

        @FXML
        private TextField minRes;

        @FXML
        private TextField crRes;

        @FXML
        private TextField maxRes;


        public static void main(String[] args) { //Проблема, скорее всего, где-то здесь
            Controller controller = new Controller();
            try {
                FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Trood.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
                so.writeObject(controller);
                so.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
                System.out.println("Невозможно создать файл");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            controller=null;

            try {
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Trood.ser"));
                Controller one = (Controller) is.readObject();
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @FXML
        private void process(ActionEvent event) throws ScriptException {

           formula(2,1,2,1,8);

           formula(1,0.5,1,2,8);

           formula(1,0.5,0.5,3,7);
        }

        @FXML
        private void formula(double a, double b, double c, int o,double l){
            double d = Double.parseDouble(dni.getText()); //Число рабояих дней
            double s = l;//Время на сон
            double e = 1;//Время на еду
            double k = a;//Не входящее не в одну категорию
            double y = b;//утрение+вечерние мероприятия
            double n = 0.83;//Неизбежные мероприятия
            double r = c;//Общий резерв
            double Vr = (24-s-e-k-y-n-r-0.83)*d;//Время на работу без учёта отдыха
            //0.83 - доля времени на общение, распределённая на день, так как общение обычно происходит 5 часов, то при разделе на 6 дней оно будет равно 0.83
            double pod=25;//время одного подхода
            double kolpod=4;//Колличество подходов

            double p = Double.parseDouble(num.getText());//Номер системы нагрузки

            if (p==2){
                pod = 30;
                kolpod =5;
            }
            if (p==3){
                pod = 35;
                kolpod =6;
            }
            if (p==4){
                pod = 40;
                kolpod =7;
            }
            if (p==5){
                pod = 45;
                kolpod =8;
            }
            if (p==6){
                pod = 50;
                kolpod =9;
            }
            if (p==7){
                pod = 55;
                kolpod =10;
            }

            double Srp=pod*kolpod; //время работы в цикле
            double So = 5*kolpod+20; //время отдыха в цикле
            double Vobsh = Srp+So; // время одного цикла с учётом работы и отдыха
            double Rrv = Vr/Vobsh*Srp; //Реальное времяф работы

            if (o==1)
            minRes.setText(String.valueOf(Rrv));
            else if (o==2)
            crRes.setText(String.valueOf(Rrv));
            else
            maxRes.setText(String.valueOf(Rrv));

        }

    }
```

Графическая часть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <HBox prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="40.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Введите число рабочих дней:">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="30.0" />
                    </HBox.margin></Text>
                <TextField fx:id="dni">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </TextField>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <children>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#process" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="121.0" text="Расчитать">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="400.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="8.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Введите номер системы:">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="30.0" />
                    </HBox.margin></Text>
                <TextField fx:id="num">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="37.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </TextField>
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets />
            </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="70.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Минимальное рабочее время:">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="200.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Text>
                <TextField fx:id="minRes">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </TextField>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <children>
                <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Среднее рабочее время:">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="200.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Text>
                <TextField fx:id="crRes">
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="51.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>
                </TextField>
            </children>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="20.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
      <HBox prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Максимальное рабочее время:" wrappingWidth="174.2890625">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="200.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="maxRes">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="12.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TextField>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Так что, ошибка ловится или просто ничего не сохраянется и работает без ошибки?

Comment: @ Dred, выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Может быть ошибаюсь, но, собственно, где у вас тут сериализация и, разве возможно записывать в файл себя ж из этого же потока?

Comment: @Dred, не знаю, но я делал по образцу

Comment: можете использовать xml для хранения данных (JAXB), в принципе обычно данный формат используют для передачи данных, а не конкретно для хранения, но в любом случае для учебных целях это полезно, ну а так же можно использовать БД (H2, MySQL и т.д.) - это что посоветовал бы я

Comment: Гуглите Java Preferences. Туда все сохраняется, оттуда потом все достается. Никаких файлов не надо, если в пределах разумного

Comment: Если для вас будет достаточно хранение данных в формате ключ-значение, смотрите на Properties, это родной для FX формат.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите, чтобы данные, введенные во время выполнения программы сохранялись и были доступны после перезапуска программы. Если так, то это можно реализовать через сохранение в файл. Вам нужны потоки `FileInputStream` и `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Их я и использую, но, почему-то, не работает